# Any standard benchmark /tool /methodology to measure latency /performance of my NIC Driver

Tags: networking, driver

I was intending to measure the latency of my networking driver (10G) using oprofile in *nix. I needed to know the standard mechanism/ tools if any to do the same ... I was thinking of netperf TCP_RR. Pls let me know if anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have a built-in bias, but netperf TCP_RR would be a good test to use to generate latency traffic.  If you include CPU utilization in the measurements (global -c and -C options to netperf) you can then do the sums on the oprofile results and compare them with what netperf reported.  Keep in mind that it may be the case that oprofile may not see code execution with interrupts disabled.  The netperf-talk mailing list hosted on netperf.org is a good place to get help with running netperf